# WFS_CMD_CDM_RESET results in WFS_SYSE_HARDWARE_ERROR

Tags: cen-xfs

ATM is Wincor/Nixdorf model ProCash 1500xe USB.
i use CDM320.exe tool to test the dispense of the ATM. when i run Reset command under ExecuteAdmin menu i get the following output:

**[10:23:54] WFSAsyncExecute ( WFS_CMD_CDM_RESET (321) ) returned WFS_SUCCESS (0) [ReqID: 87]**

[10:24:04] Event WFS_SYSE_HARDWARE_ERROR (2) arrived

```
RequestID: 0
hService: 2
tsTimestamp: [MON 14.04.2014 06:54:04,156]
szLogicalName: CDM30
szPhysicalName: CDM30
szWorkstationName: ATM
szAppID: CDM320
dwAction: WFS_ERR_ACT_NOACTION (0x0000)
dwSize: 33
bDescription
    StClass: 0x0000001D
    StCode: 0x20001814
    StWarn: 0x00000000
    sDescription: CscCngReset; SCOD=14
szDescription HEX: 1D 00 00 00 14 18 00 20 00 00 00 00 43 73 63 43 6E 67 52 65 73 65 74 3B 20 53 43 4F 44 3D 31 34 00
```

[10:24:04] WFSAsyncExecute ( WFS_CMD_CDM_RESET (321) ) completed with WFS_ERR_HARDWARE_ERROR (-14) [ReqID: 87]

what's the problem and how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a configuration issue or a genuine HW error like foreign object blocking sensor or a faulty sensor. Do you have a Wincor diagnostic software and if you do what it tells about the CDM?

PS. As I do not have experience from Wincor HW, this might be totally off the mark.

Comment: that was a problem which i couldn't resolve. they came from Wincor support and did some software work for initializing the hardware. now it's resolved. thx

Comment: Ah most probably it needed authorization of some kind like the NCR HW we use does.

Comment: @VoltagE-ThE : Hi i have posted some queries on SP devlopment of XFS. Request some guidance.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039655/implementing-new-service-provide-sp-with-cen-xfs-compliance)