# Implementing NEW service provide (SP) with CEN-XFS compliance

Tags: c++, winapi, cen-xfs

We are trying to develop windows application + device driver with CEN XFS compliance.Also, NOOB to WINDOWS applications.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEN/XFS

simple architectural flow:

```
   Windows Application
           |
  _____________________
 |      XFS APIs         |
    (CEN/XFS SDK DLL)
 |                       |
 |      XFS SPIs         |
 |_____________________|---XFS Manager   
           |
           |
    Service providers (SP)
    (DEVICE DRIVER)
```

To understand the SP's functionality, we recently took one of the device vendors SP's DLL for accessing their device and we were able to successfully communicate with their device using our windows application(Eclipse MINGW based).

Then we started  to check for some sample  SP source in internet to try our implementation. (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B60pejPe6yiSejRGQ3JnLUl4dzA/view)

With the linked source we were able to compile and create an output DLL. But , when we tried to access the SP, It always return error.

```
With windows sample application, we just tried to open the device with call (WFSOPEN) which always returned (-15 WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR ) or (-29 WFS_ERR_INVALID_SERVPROV)
```

Trial FLow 1 :

```
    Application Call to manager:

        hResult = WFSOpen(    "QuantumT",    hApp,lpszAppID,    dwTraceLevel,dwTimeOut,    VER_SPI_REQUIRE,&SrvcVersion,&SPIVersion,&hService);    

    manager translates WFSOPEN call to SP's WFPOPEN call:

        HRESULT WINAPI  WFPOpen(HSERVICE hService, LPSTR lpszLogicalName, HAPP hApp, LPSTR lpszAppID, DWORD dwTraceLevel, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, 
            REQUESTID ReqID, HPROVIDER hProvider, DWORD dwSPIVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSPIVersion, DWORD dwSrvcVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSrvcVersion)

    With above call flow I get (-29 WFS_ERR_INVALID_SERVPROV) as an error for my application
```

Trial FLow 2 (Just removed WINAPI interface for WFPOPEN in SP):

```
    Application Call to manager:
        hResult = WFSOpen(    "QuantumT",    hApp,lpszAppID,    dwTraceLevel,dwTimeOut,    VER_SPI_REQUIRE,&SrvcVersion,&SPIVersion,&hService);    

    manager translates WFSOPEN call to SP's WFPOPEN call:
        HRESULT  WFPOpen(HSERVICE hService, LPSTR lpszLogicalName, HAPP hApp, LPSTR lpszAppID, DWORD dwTraceLevel, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, 
            REQUESTID ReqID, HPROVIDER hProvider, DWORD dwSPIVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSPIVersion, DWORD dwSrvcVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSrvcVersion)

With above call flow I get (-15 WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR ) as an error for my application from manger even though i force SUCCESS as return from SP to manager
```

**I am  confused why MANAGER returns different error codes to application if WINAPI definition is removed from WFPOPEN.**

Link for WINDOWS APPLICATION SAMPLE: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B60pejPe6yiSUEp1N2xzdGlXWFE&authuser=0

SP Source (VS C++ 2010 Express):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B60pejPe6yiSejRGQ3JnLUl4dzA/view)

XFSMANAGER INSTALLER:
ftp://ftp.cencenelec.eu/CEN/WhatWeDo/Fields/ICT/eBusiness/WS/XFS/CWA15748/XFS310SDKInstall.zip

However, whneni investigate  between working DLL and DLL created by me(Using PE Studio). I see some differnece.
DLL Created by ME:

```
_WFPCancelAsyncRequest@8,-,1,-,-,.rdata:0x00001096
_WFPClose@12,-,2,-,-,.rdata:0x00001005
_WFPDeregister@20,-,3,-,-,.rdata:0x00001140
_WFPExecute@24,-,4,-,-,.rdata:0x00001131
_WFPGetInfo@24,-,5,-,-,.rdata:0x000010EB
_WFPLock@16,-,6,-,-,.rdata:0x00001023
_WFPOpen@52,-,7,-,-,.rdata:0x0000102D
_WFPRegister@20,-,8,-,-,.rdata:0x00001073
_WFPSetTraceLevel@8,-,9,-,-,.rdata:0x0000113B
_WFPUnloadService@0,-,10,-,-,.rdata:0x0000100A
_WFPUnlock@12,-,11,-,-,.rdata:0x00001082
```

Vendor created DLL:

```
WFPCancelAsyncRequest,-,1,-,-,.rdata:0x0000C450
WFPClose,-,2,-,-,.rdata:0x0000C6E0
WFPDeregister,-,3,-,-,.rdata:0x0000C7F0
WFPExecute,-,4,-,-,.rdata:0x0000C970
WFPGetInfo,-,5,-,-,.rdata:0x0000DFA0
WFPLock,-,6,-,-,.rdata:0x0000E490
WFPOpen,-,7,-,-,.rdata:0x0000C030
WFPRegister,-,8,-,-,.rdata:0x0000E590
WFPSetTraceLevel,-,9,-,-,.rdata:0x0000E710
WFPUnloadService,-,10,-,-,.rdata:0x0000E770
WFPUnlock,-,11,-,-,.rdata:0x0000E8F0
```

Even I made sure that Extern is added in my header.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
SPITEST_API HRESULT  WINAPI WFPCancelAsyncRequest(HSERVICE hService, REQUESTID RequestID);
SPITEST_API HRESULT  WINAPI WFPClose(HSERVICE hService, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
SPITEST_API HRESULT  WINAPI WFPDeregister(HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwEventClass, HWND hWndReg, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
SPITEST_API HRESULT  WINAPI WFPExecute(HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwCommand, LPVOID lpCmdData, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
SPITEST_API HRESULT  WINAPI WFPGetInfo(HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwCategory, LPVOID lpQueryDetails, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
SPITEST_API HRESULT  WINAPI WFPLock(HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
SPITEST_API HRESULT  WINAPI WFPOpen(HSERVICE hService, LPSTR lpszLogicalName, HAPP hApp, LPSTR lpszAppID, DWORD dwTraceLevel, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID, HPROVIDER hProvider, DWORD dwSPIVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSPIVersion, DWORD dwSrvcVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSrvcVersion);
SPITEST_API HRESULT  WINAPI WFPRegister(HSERVICE hService,  DWORD dwEventClass, HWND hWndReg, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
SPITEST_API HRESULT  WINAPI WFPSetTraceLevel(HSERVICE hService, DWORD dwTraceLevel);
SPITEST_API HRESULT  WINAPI WFPUnloadService();
SPITEST_API HRESULT  WINAPI WFPUnlock(HSERVICE hService, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID);
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

**Update1:**

based on the pointers giver by **Voltage** verified my code and i did not find any erro in the code flow.

Application code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "XFSAPI.H"

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

DWORD   dwThreadID;
HANDLE  hThread;
HANDLE  hEvent[2];
HWND hwnd;
#define VER_SPI_REQUIRE     0x0B020003
#define VER_XFS_REQUIRE     0x0B020003

HSERVICE        hService;


HRESULT SessionOpen(void)
{
    WFSVERSION      WFSVersion;
    DWORD           dwVersionRequired;
    HRESULT         hResult;
    HAPP            hApp=0;
    LPSTR           lpszAppID;
    DWORD           dwTraceLevel = 0;
    WFSVERSION      SrvcVersion,SPIVersion;


    hApp = WFS_DEFAULT_HAPP;
    lpszAppID = (LPSTR)"XFSTEST";

    dwVersionRequired = VER_XFS_REQUIRE;
    hResult = WFSStartUp(dwVersionRequired, &WFSVersion);

    printf("\nStart up result = %ld \n",hResult);
    printf("\n wVersion: %d \n LowVersion: %d \n wHighVersion: %d \n szDescription: %s \n szSystemStatus: %s \n",WFSVersion.wVersion,WFSVersion.wLowVersion,WFSVersion.wHighVersion,WFSVersion.szDescription,WFSVersion.szSystemStatus);
    if(hResult != WFS_SUCCESS)
    {
        return hResult;
    }

    hResult = WFSOpen(  "QuantumT",
            hApp,
            lpszAppID,
            dwTraceLevel,
            WFS_INDEFINITE_WAIT,
            VER_SPI_REQUIRE,
            &SrvcVersion,
            &SPIVersion,
            &hService);

    if(hResult == WFS_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("SrvcVersion Records: \n wVersion: %d \n LowVersion: %d \n wHighVersion: %d \n szDescription: %s \n szSystemStatus: %s \n",SrvcVersion.wVersion,SrvcVersion.wLowVersion,SrvcVersion.wHighVersion,SrvcVersion.szDescription,SrvcVersion.szSystemStatus);
    }
    printf("SrvcVersion Records: \n wVersion: %d \n LowVersion: %d \n wHighVersion: %d \n szDescription: %s \n szSystemStatus: %s \n",SrvcVersion.wVersion,SrvcVersion.wLowVersion,SrvcVersion.wHighVersion,SrvcVersion.szDescription,SrvcVersion.szSystemStatus);
    printf("SPIVersion Records: \n wVersion: %d \n LowVersion: %d \n wHighVersion: %d \n szDescription: %s \n szSystemStatus: %s \n",SPIVersion.wVersion,SPIVersion.wLowVersion,SPIVersion.wHighVersion,SPIVersion.szDescription,SPIVersion.szSystemStatus);
    printf("\nHService Address ; %ld",hService);
    Sleep(1000);

    return hResult;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        LPWFSRESULT             lpwfsResult;

        switch ( msg )
        {

            case WFS_SERVICE_EVENT:
            case WFS_USER_EVENT:
            case WFS_SYSTEM_EVENT:
            case WFS_EXECUTE_EVENT:

                lpwfsResult = (LPWFSRESULT) lParam;
                printf("\nEvent Received from XFS" );
                WFSFreeResult(lpwfsResult);
            break;

            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    HRESULT hResult = 0;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("\nSession Open In progress");


    hResult = SessionOpen();
    printf("\nSessionOpen result = %d",hResult);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**SP's WFPOpen call:**

```
HRESULT WFPOpen(HSERVICE hService, LPSTR lpszLogicalName, HAPP hApp, LPSTR lpszAppID, DWORD dwTraceLevel, DWORD dwTimeOut, HWND hWnd, REQUESTID ReqID, HPROVIDER hProvider, DWORD dwSPIVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSPIVersion, DWORD dwSrvcVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSrvcVersion)
{
        WFSRESULT * lpWFSResult;
        HRESULT  result;

        SYSTEMTIME   st;
        HRESULT  rt;

        GetSystemTime(&st);
        OutputDebugString("INTO  WFPOpen");

        printf("\nmsxfs DLL load\n");
        char strManager[MAX_PATH];
        if(0==RegGetManagerPath(strManager, sizeof(strManager))){
            if(0==GetSystemDirectoryA(strManager, sizeof(strManager)))
              return WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR;
            strcat_s(strManager, "\\msxfs.dll");
          }
          if(0!=LoadManagerFunction(strManager))
            return WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR;
          printf("\nmsxfs DLL load completed\n");
        result = m_pfnWFMAllocateBuffer(sizeof(WFSRESULT), WFS_MEM_ZEROINIT, (void**)&lpWFSResult);
        //result = WFMAllocateBuffer(sizeof(WFSRESULT), WFS_MEM_SHARE|WFS_MEM_ZEROINIT, &lpWFSResult);
        if(result!=WFS_SUCCESS)
            return WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR;
        printf("\nWFPOpen Process start\n");
        if(!g_hMutex ||!g_hLib ||!g_hMsgQueueEvent) return WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR;
        if(IsCancel(ReqID)) return WFS_ERR_CANCELED;
        CAutoLock AutoLock(g_hMutex);

      if(g_hDefThread){
            InterlockedIncrement(&g_lDefThreadRef);
            return WFS_SUCCESS;
        }else{
        bQuit=FALSE;
            g_hDefThread=BEGINTHREADEX(NULL, 0, DefThread, NULL, 0, &g_dwDefThreadId);
        if(!g_hDefThread ||g_dwDefThreadId==0)
          return WFS_ERR_CANCELED;
            InterlockedIncrement(&g_lDefThreadRef);
        }


        lpSPIVersion->wVersion=(unsigned short) dwCombineVersion(LOW_APIVERSUPPORT,HIGH_APIVERSUPPORT);
        lpSPIVersion->wLowVersion=wFloattoVersion(LOW_APIVERSUPPORT);
        lpSPIVersion->wHighVersion=wFloattoVersion(HIGH_APIVERSUPPORT);


        lpSrvcVersion->wVersion=(unsigned short ) dwCombineVersion(LOW_APIVERSUPPORT,HIGH_APIVERSUPPORT);
        lpSrvcVersion->wLowVersion=wFloattoVersion(LOW_APIVERSUPPORT);
        lpSrvcVersion->wHighVersion=wFloattoVersion(HIGH_APIVERSUPPORT);

        strcpy(lpSPIVersion->szDescription,"shHicom");
        strcpy(lpSPIVersion->szSystemStatus,"Good");
        CServiceBasic *pServiceBasic=new CServiceBasic;
        pServiceBasic->m_hService=hService;

        UINT uNameLen=min(256, strlen(lpszLogicalName));
        memcpy(pServiceBasic->m_strLogicalName, lpszLogicalName, uNameLen);
        pServiceBasic->m_strLogicalName[uNameLen]='\0';

        pServiceBasic->m_pServiceThread=hApp;
        pServiceBasic->m_strAppID=lpszAppID;
        pServiceBasic->m_dwTraceLevel=dwTraceLevel;
        pServiceBasic->m_dwTimeOut=dwTimeOut;
        pServiceBasic->m_hWND=hWnd;
        pServiceBasic->m_lpRequestID=new REQUESTID;
        *pServiceBasic->m_lpRequestID=ReqID;
        pServiceBasic->m_bAutoDeleteRequestID=TRUE;
        pServiceBasic->m_hLib=hProvider;
        pServiceBasic->m_dwSrvcVersionsRequired=dwSrvcVersionsRequired;
        pServiceBasic->m_lpSrvcVersion=lpSrvcVersion;

      if(WAIT_OBJECT_0!=WaitForSingleObject(g_hMsgQueueEvent, INFINITE))
        return WFS_ERR_CANCELED;
      BOOL b=PostThreadMessage(g_dwDefThreadId, WM_NI_SP_Open, WPARAM(pServiceBasic), 0);
      if(!b){
            return WFS_ERR_CANCELED;
      }
      printf("WFPOpen return with success\n");
    return WFS_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Service thread callback with onSpOpen**

```
LRESULT OnSPOpen(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT lr=WFS_SUCCESS;
    //return WFS_SUCCESS;
    CServiceBasic *pServiceBasic=(CServiceBasic*)wParam;
    if(pServiceBasic){
    int nLock=pServiceBasic->QueryLogicalServiceLock(pServiceBasic->m_strLogicalName);
    if(nLock<=0){
      UINT uBytes=min(strlen(pServiceBasic->m_strLogicalName), sizeof(g_strLogicalName)-1);
      memcpy(g_strLogicalName, pServiceBasic->m_strLogicalName, uBytes);
      g_strLogicalName[uBytes]='\0';
      //lr=pServiceBasic->OpenDev(g_strLogicalName, g_osp);
      lr=WFS_SUCCESS;
    }else{
        lr=WFS_ERR_CANCELED;
        }
    }else{
        lr=WFS_ERR_INVALID_HSERVICE;
    }
    WFSRESULT *pResult=NULL;
    m_pfnWFMAllocateBuffer(sizeof(WFSRESULT), WFS_MEM_ZEROINIT, (void**)&pResult);
    pResult->RequestID=*pServiceBasic->m_lpRequestID;
    pResult->hService=pServiceBasic->m_hService;
    pResult->hResult=lr;//indicate the result.
    GetLocalTime(&pResult->tsTimestamp);
    HWND hWnd=pServiceBasic->m_hWND;
    delete pServiceBasic;
  BOOL b=::PostMessage(hWnd, WFS_OPEN_COMPLETE, NULL, (LONG)pResult);
  printf ("SP Open made sure it sends WFS_OPEN_COMPLETE via POST MESSAGE\n");

  return 0;
}
```

**Console Output during execution**

C:\gtkTrials\StandAloneApp\Debug>StandAloneApp.exe

**(Print from StandAloneApp )**

```
Session Open In progress 
Start up result = 0  (WFS_SUCCESS)

 wVersion: 3
 LowVersion: 257
 wHighVersion: 39171
 szDescription: WOSA/XFS API v3.00/v2.00
 szSystemStatus:
DllMainProcessAttach is executed
```

**(Print from SP DLL )**

```
msxfs DLL load  
DLL path : C:\xfs_sdks\SDK\DLL\msxfs.dll

msxfs DLL load completed

WFPOpen Process start
DllMainProcessAttach is executed
WFPOpen return with success
SP Open made sure it sends WFS_OPEN_COMPLETE via POST MESSAGE
```

**(Print from StandAloneApp )**

```
SrvcVersion Records:
 wVersion: 3
 LowVersion: 5121
 wHighVersion: 3
 szDescription: α╝`
 szSystemStatus:
SPIVersion Records:
 wVersion: 3
 LowVersion: 5121
 wHighVersion: 3
 szDescription: shHicom
 szSystemStatus: Good



HService Address ; 1
SessionOpen result = -15 (WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR)
```

Request some pointers on understanding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Those export comparisons look like you are using wrong calling convention.
Change all your SPI exports from WINAPI to __cdecl (just remove the WINAPI as __cdecl is the default) and it should make the difference.

And why the difference in return codes in your examples:
First example doesn't even get to the WFPOpen call, because the manager doesn't find the correct WFPOpen symbol after DLL load -> Invalid ServiceProvider.

Second case seams to go in to the WFPOpen, but the first test fails -> INTERNAL_ERROR:
if(!g_hMutex ||!g_hLib ||!g_hMsgQueueEvent) return WFS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR;

So after calling convention fix you need to check your initailization code in more detail to see why it fails.

One thing I found out by looking those tested globals is that you should NEVER ever call LoadLibrary from code that is executed in DLLMain.

You could just create the mutex and save the DLL module handle in DLLMain and do rest of the initialization like library loading at the begining of the WFPOpen.

One can't simply return WFS_SUCCESS from WFPOpen.
The following is a very coarse description of the minimal implementation:
 1. Fill the version structure (One of the parameters is a pointer for this)
 2. Return WFS_SUCCESS or an error code.
 3. If WFPOpen returns WFS_SUCCESS then an asynchronous response is expected by the caller. So you have to send that WFS_OPEN_COMPLETE message with all the required information to the given (hwnd parameter) message window handle.

See more detailed information from the following document (SPI API is chapter 6).
ftp://ftp.cenorm.be/CWA/CEN/WS-XFS/CWA16374/CWA16374-1-2011_December.pdf

Comment: Reg second case: I made changes in th e code to return WFS_SUCCESS when it enters WFPOpen..Even in that case it returns -15..Surprising ..

Comment: I also made sure i commented all states where it goes and tries to communicate with the driver.

Comment: Based on your suggestions verified the flow: i was not able to point an  error on the code piece. added edit to question with code piece.

Answer (score 0):

This code is ok.
I think you should search in the registry for `QuantumT`, maybe it has not been registered there.

Logical service names:

1. regedit
2. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/XFS/LOGICAL_SERVICES/`

I use `JournalPrinter1` and WFSOpen returns “Success” to me.

Answer (score 0):

The calling convention is already defined in `XFSSPI.H`, I don't think you should change it.

You need to add a .def file to your solution with the "correct" exported name of the functions, and set it as your solution Module Definition File `Properties->Linker->Input->Module Definition File`:

```
EXPORTS
WFPCancelAsyncRequest
WFPClose
WFPDeregister
WFPExecute
WFPGetInfo
WFPLock
WFPOpen
WFPRegister
WFPSetTraceLevel
WFPUnloadService
WFPUnlock
```

I got my `SPI` `WFPOpen` function called this way.